# Play Framework 2.3.x - Easy way to change/refresh a view asynchronous

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I only want to refresh or manipulate a view by a ajax event.

I have 3 views in use, the main-one includes the navigation one and details view, so that the main.scale.html looks shorted like this:

```
       <div class="well">
            <div class="row fullheight">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                @views.html.nav()
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                @views.html.details("some header")
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now my desire is, that I can click something in the nav and it appears asynchronous in the details-scope. 
I was able to call a controller-methode by using ajax from the javascript site. 
But now I have no idea how to rerender or reload only the details-view.

In JS, by code for call the controller-methode:

```
    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.loadDetailsToTree(data.node.title).ajax({
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("all fine.");
        },
        error : function(err) {
            alert("error");            
        }
    });
```

This works and calls this method in Application.java:

```
    public static Result loadDetailsToTree(String tcTitle) {
        //doing something with the data in the model
        //no idea what to do here to refresh or manipulate the details-view:
        return ok(...);
    }
```

Only need to refresh (because the data from /getData are changed).

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/detailsTree.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<div id="confTree" class="confTree" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    var callback = function(data) {
       console.log("Callback fired with: " + data);
       $("#confTree").detailsTreeBuilder(data, null);
    };
    $.post('/getData', callback);
</script>
```

My problem is that I can't read scala code and my examples are written in this :(
And yes I'm pretty sure, that I have misunderstanding in the way to use it. Maybe some of you guys are friendly enough to help me :)

cheers,
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that It is possible.

Instead of that you can do.

Suppose you have 3 view

```
<div id="view1">@view1</div>
<div id="view2">@view2</div>
<div id="view3">@view3</div>
```

Onload of page show only 1 `<div>`

```
<script>
 $ ( document ).ready ( function ( ) { 
   $("#view1").show();
    $("#view2").hide();
    $("#view3").hide();
    } ) ;
</script>
```

Do you ajax call and get a string from controller(return "view2" to display view2 and so on)

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.loadDetailsToTree(data.node.title).ajax({
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("all fine.");

                if(data==="view2"){
                   $("#view1").hide();
                   $("#view2").show();
                   $("#view3").hide();

               }else if(data==="view3"){
                        $("#view1").hide();
                        $("#view2").hide();
                        $("#view3").show();

}

        },
        error : function(err) {
            alert("error");            
        }
    });
```